# Chain rule error

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Find $\frac{ \partial ^2 f}{ \partial x ^2}$ where $f(x,y,z)=h(r)$ in $R^3$ except  $(0,0,0)$ and $r$ is the usual radius.

Attempt: see [here](https://www.camscanner.net/share/4qoi4/0/w105s10jd4f52)

> $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \dfrac{\operatorname{d} h}{\operatorname{d} r}\dfrac{\partial r}{\partial x}$
>
> Where $f(x,y,z)=h(r), r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$
>
> $\therefore \dfrac{\partial r}{\partial x} = \dfrac{2x}{2\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}} = \dfrac{x}{r}$
>
> $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}= \dfrac{\operatorname{d} h}{\operatorname{d} r}\cdot\dfrac{x}{r}$
>
> $\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\;^2}=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(\dfrac{\operatorname{d} h}{\operatorname{d} r}\cdot\dfrac{x}{r}\right)\cdot\dfrac{\partial r}{\partial x} = \\ \quad \left(\dfrac{\operatorname{d}^2 h}{\operatorname{d} r\;^2}\cdot\dfrac{x}{r}-\dfrac{\operatorname{d} h}{\operatorname{d} r}\cdot\dfrac{x}{r^2}\right)\cdot\dfrac{x}{r}$
>
> The book: $h''(r)\dfrac{x^2}{r^2} + h'(r) \left(\dfrac{1}{r}-\dfrac{x^2}{r^3}\right) \neq -h'(r)\dfrac{x^2}{r^3}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\;^2}=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(\dfrac{\operatorname{d} h}{\operatorname{d} r}\cdot\dfrac{x}{r}\right)\cdot\dfrac{\partial r}{\partial x} = \left(\dfrac{\operatorname{d}^2 h}{\operatorname{d} r\;^2}\cdot\dfrac{x}{r}-\dfrac{\operatorname{d} h}{\operatorname{d} r}\cdot\dfrac{x}{r^2}\right)\cdot\dfrac{x}{r}$

No.  The product rule is: $\frac{\partial }{\partial z}(\color{blue}{u}\cdot \color{green}{v})= \color{blue}{u}\cdot \frac{\partial \color{green}{v}}{\partial z}+\frac{\partial\color{blue}{u}}{\partial z}\cdot \color{green}{v}$

$\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\;^2} = \dfrac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(\color{blue}{\dfrac{\operatorname{d} h}{\operatorname{d} r}}\cdot\color{green}{\dfrac{x}{r}}\right)\cdot\dfrac{\partial r}{\partial x} \\ \quad \quad = \left(\color{blue}{\dfrac{\operatorname{d}^2 h}{\operatorname{d}r\;^2}}\cdot\color{green}{\dfrac{x}{r}}+\color{blue}{\dfrac{\operatorname{d} h}{\operatorname{d} r}}\cdot\left(\color{green}{\dfrac{\partial}{\partial r}\dfrac{x}{r}}\right)\right)\dfrac{\partial r}{\partial x} \\ \quad \quad = \dfrac{\operatorname{d}^2 h}{\operatorname{d}r\;^2}\cdot\dfrac{x}{r}\cdot\dfrac{\partial r}{\partial x}+\dfrac{\operatorname{d} h}{\operatorname{d} r}\cdot\left(\dfrac{\partial r}{\partial x}\cdot\dfrac{\partial}{\partial r}\dfrac{x}{r}\right) \\ \quad \quad = \left(\dfrac{\operatorname{d}^2 h}{\operatorname{d}r\;^2}\right)\cdot\dfrac{x^2}{r^2}+\dfrac{\operatorname{d} h}{\operatorname{d} r}\cdot\left(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\dfrac{x}{r}\right) \\ \quad \quad = \left(\dfrac{\operatorname{d}^2 h}{\operatorname{d}r\;^2}\right)\cdot\dfrac{x^2}{r^2}+\dfrac{\operatorname{d} h}{\operatorname{d} r}\cdot\left(\dfrac{1}{r} - \dfrac{x^2}{r^3}\right)$

$\therefore \dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\;^2}=\dfrac{x^2}{r^2}h''(r) + \dfrac{r^2-x^2}{r^3} h'(r)$

Comment: it was the quotient rule at $x/r$ that got me. writing $r(x)$ or even $\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ instead of just $r$ on a sheet of paper and the studying your answer helped me here.